# Import remote .sql file to local mysql db using SSH tunel

Tags: mysql, database, ssh, cat, diskspace

I have a big .sql file ~200 GB in a remote server, and I want to import it to a local MySQL DB. of course I can download it and then import it using :

```
mysql -u root mydbname < file.sql
```

But the problem is that I will not have enough local disk space during/after import.

That's why I'm thinking about a way to import it directly to my local without downloading it (to not have disk space issues).
I found a command but I have concerns that it could impact the performance of the remote server since it tries to open the file remotely and then execute it locally:

```
ssh username@server-ip "cat /path/file.sql" | mysql -u .. -p .. mydb
```

Could you please support?

Comment: you already gave yourself the answers to your question.

Comment: But is it OK to open a 200 GB file in the server using cat? I think it will impact the performance. or am I wrong?

Comment: Oh, definitely. It's going to take a long time to import 200GB, no matter how you do it. How long depends a lot on your tables, indexes, and a lot on the performance of your database server CPU and storage.

Comment: I'm not talking about the time taken to process the file, but I have concerns about the performance of the remote server since it's a production server. I think the cat command will impact the memory of the remote server.

Comment: Cat is very low impact. It's just opening the file and reading it. There is no other way to read the file that is lower impact. Even if you had enough disk space on your local server to transfer the file, you'd still be reading that file to do the transfer, which would have exactly the same impact as cat does.

Comment: ok then loading the data will have an impact on the remote server, and I don't want that. I'm wondering if there is any other solution. something like downloading the SQL command lines from the SQL file 1 by 1 and executing it locally... well I'm just imagining ...

Comment: You could use `nice` to reduce the priority, but one way or another reading the file will have nonzero impact, no matter how you do it.